# What exactly does this JavaScript do?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's a script found on my site.

```
var domains = ["abc.net", "abc.com", "abc.info", "abc.blogspot.com"];
if (domains.indexOf(document.location.hostname) == -1 && document.cookie.indexOf('opened=true') == -1) {
    window.top.location = "http://abc.net";
    document.cookie = "opened=true";
}
```

I don't know what it does but it always redirect to `abc.net`. Can somebody explain its working to me?

Comment: i think it checks if the url of the current page is in that domains array and if not redirect it to abc.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var domains = ["abc.net", "abc.com", "abc.info", "abc.blogspot.com"]; //urls that can be allowed
    if (domains.indexOf(document.location.hostname) == -1 && document.cookie.indexOf('opened=true') == -1) //checks if it is in the list of "domains"
{
        window.top.location = "http://abc.net"; //then redirects to "http://abc.net"
        document.cookie = "opened=true";  //creates cookie 'opened' and sets it to true
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I dont understand this part //creates cookie 'opened' and sets it to true. Mind to explain a lil bit more?

Comment: JavaScript can create cookies, read cookies, and delete cookies with the property document.cookie.

Answer (score 0):

It checks if the document's domain name is not in the list, and checks if the document cooked does not contain opened=true, and if both are true, it redirects the top level document to http://abc.net, and sets the document cookie to opened=true. If I'm not mistaken, this code is used to break-out of any frame another website may have opened the website with this script in.

Comment: `window.top.location` is susceptible to the *same origin policy* so it cannot break out of an iframe another website (e.g. another domain) has opened.

Comment: @DavidTitarenco: Do you have a source for that? I have successfully used similar code to redirect the browsers of users viewing websites in frames for years, without any issue. I'd be interested to hear if this has changed.

Comment: I'm finding contradicting sources so I need to test this myself. I was pretty sure all `.location` directives were cross-domain protected (as far as iframe->parent operations were concerned) but maybe I'm wrong.